# Tornado + Mongo : What is the difference between Motor & Motorengine?

Tags: tornado, tornado-motor

*Motor uses a clever greenlet-based approach to fully support both synchronous and asynchronous interfaces from a single codebase.*

And as Motorengine docs claim it is to be used when you don’t want your ioLoop to be blocked while doing I/O to mongoDB.

So essentially, Motor claims async operations and Motorengine claims non-blocking I/O.

Can somebody please clarify the difference between the two in this context?

Is there a difference b/w how motor returns calls to DB and how motorengine does? What am I missing or how will I be limited if I use motor instead on Motorengine in terms of blocking, schema, speed ?

Answer (score 2):

Motor is just a driver, it's relatively low-level. It's officially supported by MongoDB and I maintain it. MotorEngine is a project external to MongoDB Inc and authored by a member of our community. It is an Object Document Mapper that adds a bunch of convenience features and syntactic sugar on top of Motor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although, I find it too abstract for myself. So I'm trying to ask a better question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30641824/does-motorengine-mantain-an-io-stream-with-mongo-db if you would like to give your valuable thoughts.